# Laravel taking url string as parameter

Tags: php, laravel-5

So basically i want to create a route like `http://example.com/{page_slug}` on my laravel app, but when i register that in my routes file it affects pages like `http://example.com/login` as it give me an error related to page "login" not found.

Here is my route with the page slug parameter

```
Route::get('/{slug}','Admin\PageController@viewPage');
```

The login route id generated automatically, i'm using laravel 5.4

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

All i had to do was put the

```
Route::get('/{slug}','Admin\PageController@viewPage');
```

As the last route, so other routes would be checked first.